# Sidebar slide navigation using list item using jQuery

Tags: jquery

In the sidebar menu list items are side very well but under the children, children of children items are not slide.

```
    <ul class="side">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
            <ul class="inner">
                <li><a href="#">Item 2: 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2: 2</a></li>
                    <ul class="doubleinner">
                        <li><a href="#">Item 2: 2: 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 2: 2: 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2: 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2: 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
            <ul class="inner">
                <li><a href="#">Item 3: 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3: 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3: 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

my jQuery look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.inner li').hide();

$('.side > li').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $('.side > li').not(this).find('li').slideUp();
        $(this).find('.inner li').slideDown();
        return false;
    });
});
});
```

I want to slide under class "doubleinner". How to do that? I need to slide up and down under "Item 2:2".

here: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Reaper/MP4k4/)

It is a experimental and educational script I am coding, and I am not in pro yet. :)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your nested ul li is wrong. Second li of inner class should close after doubleinner ul.
2. Try below js.

   $(document).ready(function() {

   ```
   $('ul ul').hide();

   $('li a').click(function ()
   {
       if(!$(this).parent('li').hasClass('open'))
       {
           $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').find('li.open').find('ul').slideUp();
           $(this).parent('li').parent('ul').find('li').removeClass('open');
           $(this).parent('li').addClass('open');
           $(this).parent('li.open').children('ul').slideDown();
       }
   });
   ```

and html is

```
<ul class="side">
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
                <ul class="inner">
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2: 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2: 2</a>
                        <ul class="doubleinner">
                            <li><a href="#">Item 2: 2: 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item 2: 2: 2</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2: 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2: 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
                <ul class="inner">
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3: 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3: 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 3: 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `>` [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators) you are binding the click event only on the `<li>`elements **directly inside** `.side`, so the `<li>` inside `.inner` are not touch by this definition.
And you are never showing in the code .doubleinner. From the code it's not clear if .doubleinner is supposed to be the only one of "second level", if this is the case here you can find a solution that doesn't break your code (just adds something): http://jsfiddle.net/MP4k4/6/

Answer (score 0):

You should put second list items in first list items li and distinguish if the inner ones are clicked or the parent ones with `if`. JSFiddle below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.inner li').hide();

$('li').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $('.doubleinner > li').not(this).find('.doubleinner li').slideUp();
        if($(this).parent().attr('class') == 'side')
        $(this).find('ul > li').not('.doubleinner > li').slideDown();
        else
        $(this).find('.doubleinner li').slideDown();                
        return false;
    });
});

});

    <ul class="side">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
            <ul class="inner">
                <li><a href="#">Item 2: 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2: 2</a>
                    <ul class="doubleinner">
                        <li><a href="#">Item 2: 2: 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 2: 2: 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2: 3</a>
                    <ul class="doubleinner">
                        <li><a href="#">Item 2: 3: 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 2: 3: 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2: 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
            <ul class="inner">
                <li><a href="#">Item 3: 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3: 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3: 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MP4k4/8/)